# Prompt "Use USB to ... (charge this device, ...)" keeps coming up

Tags: usb, sony-xperia

I'm trying to connect my Xperia X to my laptop and after hitting "Transfer files" connection is attempted but won't establish and defaults back to charging. Doesn't matter how many times I tap on "Transfer files". I'm using genuine USB cable from Sony so cable can't be the issue. Do I need any specific driver or something ?

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

**Hardware IDS:**

[image]

Comment: I don't know how Windows inside VMWare works, but Windows users usually need to install [USB OEM driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers) first.

Comment: @AndrewT.  Yes, that's one of the things I've already done. I downloaded relevant driver for Xperia X and when I tried to use it Windows came back to me with "This device is already using the best driver". Obviously not, I'm thinking ...

Comment: as for all virtual machines you need usb passthrough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course,for connecting phone to Pc you need phone's drivers. I see that you made a Windows Virtual Machine and there are 2 ways to solve it:

1st Way: Installing Drivers Manually
For installing driver manually go to Device manager->Details->Hardware ID copy all ID and search on Google. After that you will see your phone's driver name. Search that driver name and install it.

2nd Way(Easiest way):Use driver updater software for Windows.

If you are not professional at Windows OS,then there special programs for you such as Advanced Driver Updater,IOBit Driver Booster(in app you will see "update drivers" option.) and etc. If these ways not works then go to [this site](https://androidmtk.com/download-sony-xperia-usb-driver) and find your device. Then at the right you will see driver. Click on that link and download that driver and install.

I hope this steps will help you.

Comment: Internet search for the hw ids didn't yield satisfying results. I used Driver Booster by iObit which in many cases can be very useful tool. In this case it said I'm using latest driver. The driver updater that comes with Windows says that I'm already using the best driver. If that's so why can't I transfer any files from the phone through USB ?

Based on what you see in the screenshot, which device's driver needs to be updated ? The USB controller or Xperia X device itself ? I reckon I should be looking at USB controllers. I'm not sure which device to install the Sony's driver on.

Comment: I've added another screenshot.

Comment: Try to delete device drivers from Device Manager and reconnect your phone. @Mark

Comment: I'm starting to think that how VMware handles USB connections is here to blame. Because when I disconnected the phone from VMware and connected the phone to my Linux (host) the connection was established without an issue. What I'm gonna do is to make my laptop dual boot with W10 instead of using VMware. Will report back.

Comment: @Mark ,if you don't face with this problem on host machine then it means there is problem with VMware. You will not face with this problem after making Windows 10 as secondary OS.

Comment: Yes, in my particular case VMware was making the trouble. After I installed W10 on separate partition I had no problem connecting the phone. No pop ups either. VMware is great but not perfect if you need to work with USB devices.